# Searching Array list of objects

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an array list in a class the array is called realtorList. From my main class I store objects with realtor data to the realtorList. 
My data that is stored to a text file and is read in the first line. 
This is the first element in the realtorList after I store the first line of data.

[Realtor{licenseNumber=**AA1111111**, firstName=Anna, lastName=Astrid, phoneNumber=111-111-1111,
commission=0.011}]

When I read the next line of data from the input file I need to see if the licenseNumber in bold already exists in the realtorList. I am having trouble figuring out how to go about doing this.

For example if the next realtor data license number is AA1111111 how do I check the realtorList for AA1111111 which does exist for this example.

Comment: Why not just loop through realtorList and check the read license number against each element? It's slow, but so is almost anything you try unless you store the information in something like a MySQL database.

Comment: a `Map` might be usefull here.

Comment: That is part i am having trouble with, how to pull just the license number out when I call the first element realtorList.get(0). How do i just read the license number?

Comment: Just use a `Map<String, Realtor>` and use the license number as a key. Then check whether that map already contains a value for the license number you're about to import.

Comment: You might want to provide some info on what the data in the list looks like. If it is `Realtor` objects (or similar) then `realtorList.get(0).getLicenseNumber()` should work (assuming you provide that method) - if it is a `List<String>` then either use a regular expression or better parse those strings to `Realtor` objects and use the first approach.

Comment: This is the first exact element that returns when call get(0) [Realtor{licenseNumber=AA1111111, firstName=Anna, lastName=Astrid, phoneNumber=111-111-1111, commission=0.011}]      my array list is called in the class private ArrayList realtorList = new ArrayList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple way to do this would be to have a String ArrayList running alongside (for example, one called licenses) and use an if statement with indexOf to return if that license value is already in the List. Since the licenses ArrayList only has one value it can be easily searched with indexOf.

An example would be

```
private boolean checkLicense (String licenseNumber) {
        int i = licenses.indexOf(licenseNumber);
        if(i == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Similar code works in one of my projects where a dynamic List of motors for a robot checks to see if there's already a motor with the listed port before adding a new one.

Another method could use a for loop for a linear search such as

```
private boolean checkLicense (String licenseNumber) {
   for(int i = 0; i < (realtorList.size() - 1); i++) {
      if (licenseNumber.equals(realtorList[i].getLicenseNumber())) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

This would perform a linear search of each and every object until it finds it (it would need to be in a method like the one for the example above to work this way)

Comment: you're sure to compare strings using "==" operator?

Comment: Ah whoops. I aught to fix that since the original code I modified to fit this example compared Integers. I'll edit it.

Comment: If i use if (license.equals(realtorList.get(count).getlicenseNumber)) the .getlicenseNumber is highlighted in red and hovering over it says java.lang.Object.getlocenseNumber.

Comment: I am using this             
for (int count = 0; count < realtorList.size(); count++ )
{
                holdList = realtorList.get(count).toString();
                int i = holdList.indexOf(license);
                if (i == -1)
                {
                    uniqueResult = true;
                    //System.out.println("not found");
                }
                else
                {   //System.out.println("found" + i);
                    uniqueResult = false;
                }
            }

Comment: I can't tell what exactly your for loop is doing, but I'm fairly sure that you're code is not giving you anything near what you want (toString by default gives the name and code of the object), you'd be better off using the linear search for loop that I gave you in the answer, which searches the licenseNumber variable of each object with a getLicenseNumber() accessor method.

Comment: I think i am missing the method getLicenseNumber() thats why I could not run the linear search. What would I put in that method. I cannot figure out how to check the license number that is what this whole post is about.

Comment: The getLicenseNumber() would simply return a String containing the licenseNumber variable. The getLicenseNumber() method needs to be in the object's class. It's a simple accessor method that you'll need for this to work.